# Die Bedeutung von "nur mal so"

Tags: modal-particle

> Warum lachst Du
>   oder lachst Du **nur mal so**
>   warum weinst Du
>   oder weinst Du **nur mal so**
>   Ich stolper durch die Straßen
>   und bin total verwirrt
>   selbst wenn Du Brötchen holst
>   bin ich schon irritiert

Ich möchte wissen, was der Ausdruck "nur mal so" in diesem Lied bedeutet.

Comment: "Just because" or "for no reason" should work here.

Comment: Hast Du in einem Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen? Was hast Du gefunden? Welche Frage ist offen geblieben?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nur mal so** bedeutet **ohne besonderen Grund**.

> "Warum lachst Du, oder lachst Du ohne besonderen Grund?"

hat die gleiche Bedeutung wie der Satz aus den Liedtext.